# Can't run python programs in command prompt even though I have added python to Path

Tags: python-3.7

I can use "python" command in Command prompt and it works fine but when I try to run a python file in Command prompt this message pops up. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojv7c.jpg
Yesterday I could run my python program normally but today when I tried again, the entire code from that program that I ran yesterday was deleted and I can't run any python programs in Command prompt anymore. Python command still works though. My Python version is 3,7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I order to run a python script in python you need to specify that Python should be used. So your command would be

```
python Test.py
```

Comment: Looks like you've run "Testi.py" rather than "Test.py" - is that the right filename?

Comment: The filename is actually Test.py but it still gives the same error message https://imgur.com/1TNQMtt

Comment: Is your python file stored on the desktop? That error is telling you that Python can't find the file you're asking for. You can use the dir command to list all of the files in your current directory. Make sure that the file you are running is in the directory you are referencing.

Comment: Okay, if I try to run some program that is in my python folder it runs just fine now. But still if I have the file on desktop, Command prompt can't find it for some reason

Comment: Try putting the full file path, eg C:/Users etc etc

Comment: No worries dude